# How to check VPS is performing optimally?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, page-speed

Like for measuring Load time of a website we have [Pingdom tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/), do we have something similar to measure if the VPS I currently have is good or not.

I'm looking for some kind of metrics, because I have simple one page wordpress website which according to Pingtool takes approximately 30 secs and then timesout, that's pretty(x 10) bad. The same website on a different server takes 8 seconds. So I'm guessing something wrong with the VPS.

Also I'm running Ubuntu with virtualmin on VPS. Its 512 MB ram and

Comment: Even 8 seconds is a way too much (unless you have extremely bad code .. or this VPS is running on very CPU-busy/low-on-memory server).

Comment: yeah... 6 seconds seems to be a good benchmark. Any higher than that means something needs fixing...

Comment: For WordPress, I consider anything that is over 1 sec a HUGE delay for such single-page website. WordPress is not fastest solution (as it built to satisfy most usage scenarios via plugins so extra not-necessary-for-you code is still running behind), but definitely is not slowest around. Try [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugin to speed this up (if that is possible for you). I do not know what is your website is .. but for a one-page website consider building it without any CMS -- just plain PHP (if needed), if site is static -- HTML only.

Answer (score 2):

> Like for measuring Load time of a website we have Pingdom tools, do we
>   have something similar to measure if the VPS I currently have is good
>   or not.

[UnixBench](http://code.google.com/p/byte-unixbench/) is a popular Linux benchmarking script for gathering performance statistics, however, running a benchmarking script may put you at odds with your hosting provider's resource abuse policies and, as you are sharing a server, the resources available to your VPS (*especially* disk I/O - and *even more so* if you are using swap) at a given point in time will depend upon what your neighbors are doing.

> I have simple one page wordpress website which according to Pingtool
>   takes approximately 30 secs and then timesout, that's pretty(x 10)
>   bad. The same website on a different server takes 8 seconds. So I'm
>   guessing something wrong with the VPS.

If you are running MySQL and Apache with PHP in a 512MB environment without tweaking their configurations to run together in a low-memory environment, the problem is most likely with your configuration.

Comment: What are the most common configurations that need to be taken care of, to get immediate boost.

Comment: @Nikhil - To get things running, I would recommend you review the [MySQL server optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-the-server.html) docs and the [LowEndBox optimization guides](http://www.lowendbox.com/wiki/#software-optimization-guide), and, once you can confirm that WordPress is working, take a look at WordPress caching plugins (like [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/)).